# Unable to query first child item in Firebase Android SDK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to get the first child item from a Firebase ref in a ValueEventListener.  If I setup the listener as follows, I'll get the correct number of children printed out.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }
            });
```

If I do any of the following:

```
ref.orderByPriority().limitToFirst(1)

ref.startAt().limit(1)
```

I don't get the first child - I get zero children, and the DataSnapshot returned is null.

What might I be doing wrong?

**Update**, I changed my gradle import from `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:1.+` to compile `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:1.1.1+`.  Must have been a bug in whatever SDK version that was pulling down.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes, see the update.  Newer versions of the client perform as expected.  The changelog [1] details some newer methods that make this simpler.  [1] https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/changelog.html

Comment: Can you look at this? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563023/how-to-get-all-users-email-id-in-firebase-for-android-platform